# Number of vectors which are $\alpha$ angle apart

Tags: combinatorics, complex-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Let, $A\subseteq\{z=(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2:|z|^2=|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=1\}$ such that any two vectors in $A$ have angle between them $\ge\alpha$ for some $0<\alpha<1$. I want to prove that $$\#A=O(\alpha^{-1}) \ \ for \ \ \epsilon>0.$$ If the whole problem is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{C}^2$, then by a careful use of pigeon-hole principle I can prove that $\#A=O(\alpha^{-1})$, while I have no idea how to prove in complex case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a saving, is it, if $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: Yes it is positive.

Comment: Then it's not a saving, right? $O(\alpha^{-1})$ is *smaller* than $O(\alpha^{-(1-\epsilon)}$.

Comment: Well, I actually thought about $\alpha<1$ case. Then it would be a saving indeed. Sorry about that.

Comment: If $\alpha<1$ then isn't $O(1)$ better than $O(\alpha^{-1+\epsilon})$?

Comment: I actually completely messed the previous question up. I actually proved in $\mathbb{R}^2$ case and thought to have a mimic proof in complex case, while it is becoming very difficult for me to 'visualize' what 'an angle between two vectors in $\mathbb{C}^2$' is.